# How do I disable the hardware buttons on my CanoScan LiDE 600F scanner?

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, scanner, canon-lide

I'd like to completely disable the hardware buttons on my CanoScan LiDE 600F scanner. I never use them, and they are constantly getting pressed accidentally. May need a registry hack.

I'm talking about [these buttons](http://www.usa.canon.com/CUSA/assets/app/images/scanner/LiDE700/ez.jpg) (different model, but you get the picture).

The CanoScan Toolbox Settings only lets me reassign their functions, not disable them completely. I've checked on Canon's website, and I have the most up to date software. Can I edit settings in the Registry to do this? E.g. I can see the button assignments in
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Canon\CanoScan Toolbox Ver5.0\Devices\CanoScan LiDE 600F

But I am not qualified to blindly fiddle with the Registry. I'm hoping someone who is more qualified, and ideally has a similar scanner, could advise.

Answer (score 0):

Got a solution via Ask Metafilter: Turns out I could simply **uninstall the CanoScan Toolbox software**, and scan via other apps using the TWAIN driver (as I've been doing anyway).